# Need Help Finding Solution to These 5 Simple Exponent Exercises

Tags: exponential-function, fractions, exponential-sum

In this document, I have 5 exercises involving exponents and their five corresponding solutions. I am trying to find out why these are the solutions for these equations, as I cannot seem to get the same results as the provided solutions. The exercises ask to simplify the following equations. Can anyone assist in explaining how to solve for these five equations?

Thank you!

[Exponent Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emd9w.png)

http://i349.photobucket.com/albums/q368/Chaplive/Screenshot%2035_zpsx2sjpp5f.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to Math.SE Christian. It is always better if you trype out questions using mathjax: link to the guide on how to do that [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). I'll answer your question anyway this time, but please bear this in mind in future.

When we work with powers, there are two critical rules to remember.
$$a^n\cdot a^m=a^{n+m}[I]$$
$$\frac{a^n}{a^m}=a^{n-m} [II]$$

For the first question, note that $(-k)^n\equiv k^n$ IF $n$ is even. It is in this case, so you use rule $[II]$ for $$\frac{3^4}{3^5}=3^{4-5}=3^{-1}$$

For the second question: Note that $k^{-n}=\frac{1}{k^n}$, thus $2^{-1}=\frac 12, 2^{-2}=\frac{1}{2^2}=\frac 14$. Thus the numerator is: $$\frac 12 + \frac 14=\frac 34$$
and the denominator is:
$$\frac 12 \cdot \frac 14 =\frac 18$$
To evaluate$\frac{(\frac 34)}{(\frac 18)}$, note this is equivalent to $\frac 34 \cdot \frac 81$ and go from there.

For your third question, some new rules come into play:
$$m^xn^x=(mn)^x [III]$$
and $${(m^n)}^x=m^{nx} [IV]$$

Using these two, you can simplify your equation to:
$$\frac{3^{16}\cdot2^{18}}{2^{16}\cdot 3^{16}}=2^2=4$$

For Question $4$, note $(-1)^n$ is $-1$ if $n$ is odd, and $1$ if $n$ is even. So your equation becomes:
$$-(1)-(-1)-(-1)-(1)=-1+1+1-1=0$$
For the fifth question, note anything (except $0$) to the power $0$ is $1$.

Thus you have: $$\frac{1}{5^{-1}+5^{-2}}$$
Using the $5^{-n}=\frac{1}{5^n}$ rule, we can then find this is $$\frac{1}{(\frac{6}{25})}=\frac{25}{6}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply!!  It took me a while to understand your explanation of exercises 2 and 3, however after going back to how to add fractions and how to simplify larger exponents I understood. I'd like to ask to make sure if the reason for answer #3 being 2 to the 2th power is because 3 to the 16th power divided by itself would be 1, which doesnt matter. So 2 to the 18th power divided by 2 to the 16th should be the division used to find the correct solution right? Also!! Ill make sure to use math jack for future posts.

Comment: You are right when you say that the $3^{16}$s would cancel. With regards to $\frac{2^{18}}{2^{16}}$, use rule $[II]$, and you get that $\frac{2^{18}}{2^{16}}=2^{18-16}=2^2=4$

Comment: If anything else doesn't make sense, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Perfect!! Last question on my mind. What would be the greatest path in simplifying large exponents such as 81 to the fourth power. Because finding that 3 to the 4th would be 81 seems like a bit of guess work for me.

Comment: You could notice that $81=9^2$, so $81^4=9^{2\cdot4}=9^8$, and then note $9=3^2$, so $9^8=3^{2\cdot8}=3^{16}$

Comment: Amazing. Thanks *thumbs up*

Comment: If you'd like to give me a thumbs up, there's an up-arrow at the top of my answer for you to show that. You may also wish (and it is good etiquette) to hit the tick to accept the answer you think is the best for your question.

Answer (score 1):

$1)$ Use the law of exponents ie $a^{-n}=\frac1{a^n}$

so $(-3)^4\div3^5=\frac{(-1)^43^4}{3^5}=3^{4-5}=3^{-1}$

$2)$ $\dfrac{2^{-1}+2^{-2}}{2^{-1}\cdot2^{-2}}=\frac{2^{-1}}{2^{-3}}+\frac{2^{-2}}{2^{-3}}= 2^2+2=6$

$3)$ note that $(a\cdot b)^c = a^c\cdot b^c$

$\dfrac{81^4\cdot4^9}{6^{16}}= \dfrac{3^{4\cdot4}\cdot2^{2\cdot9}}{3^{16}\cdot2^{16}}=\dfrac{3^{16}\cdot2^{18}}{3^{16}\cdot2^{16}}= 2^2 =4$

$4)$ remember that $(-1)^{even}= 1$ and $(-1)^{odd}=-1$

$-(-1)^2-(-1^5)-(-1)^7-(-1)^{100} = -(1)-(-1)-(-1)-(1) =-1+1+1-1 = 0$

$5)$ $a^0 =1$  so,

$\dfrac{(5^{-1}+5^{-2})^0}{5^{1}+5^{-2}}= \dfrac{1}{\frac15+\frac1{25}}=\frac{1}{\frac{5+1}{25}}=\dfrac{25}6$